# Pretty (dated) RESTful URLs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rest, slug

I'd like my website to have URLs looking like this:

```
example.com/2010/02/my-first-post
```

I have my `Post` model with `slug` field ('my-first-post') and `published_on` field (from which we will deduct the year and month parts in the url).

I want my `Post` model to be RESTful, so things like `url_for(@post)` work like they should, ie: it should generate the aforementioned url.

Is there a way to do this? I know you need to override `to_param` and have `map.resources :posts` with `:requirements` option set, but I cannot get it all to work.

---

I have it almost done, I'm 90% there. Using [resource_hacks plugin](http://github.com/stengland/resource-hacks-plugin) I can achieve this:

```
map.resources :posts, :member_path => '/:year/:month/:slug',
  :member_path_requirements => {:year => /[\d]{4}/, :month => /[\d]{2}/, :slug => /[a-z0-9\-]+/}

rake routes
(...)
post GET    /:year/:month/:slug(.:format)      {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}
```

and in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'post', post_path(:slug => @post.slug, :year => '2010', :month => '02') %>
```

generates proper `example.com/2010/02/my-first-post` link.

I would like this to work too:

```
<%= link_to 'post', post_path(@post) %>
```

But it needs overriding the `to_param` method in the model. Should be fairly easy, except for the fact, that `to_param` must return `String`, not `Hash` as I'd like it.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
   {:slug => 'my-first-post', :year => '2010', :month => '02'}
  end
end
```

Results in `can't convert Hash into String` error.

This seems to be ignored:

```
def to_param
  '2010/02/my-first-post'
end
```

as it results in error: `post_url failed to generate from {:action=>"show", :year=>#<Post id: 1, title: (...)` (it wrongly assigns @post object to the :year key). I'm kind of clueless at how to hack it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still a hack, but the following works:

In `application_controller.rb`:

```
def url_for(options = {})
  if options[:year].class.to_s == 'Post'
    post = options[:year]
    options[:year] = post.year
    options[:month] = post.month
    options[:slug] = post.slug
  end
  super(options)
end
```

And the following will work (both in Rails 2.3.x and 3.0.0):

```
url_for(@post)
post_path(@post)
link_to @post.title, @post
etc.
```

This is the answer from some [nice soul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17674/anshul) for a similar question of mine, [url_for of a custom RESTful resource (composite key; not just id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263488/url-for-of-a-custom-restful-resource-composite-key-not-just-id).

Answer (score 5):

Pretty URLs for Rails 3.x and Rails 2.x without the need for any external plugin, but with a little hack, unfortunately.

routes.rb

```
map.resources :posts, :except => [:show]
map.post '/:year/:month/:slug', :controller => :posts, :action => :show, :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :slug => /[a-z0-9\-]+/
```

application_controller.rb

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
  # resource hack so that url_for(@post) works like it should
  if options[:controller] == 'posts' && options[:action] == 'show'
    options[:year] = @post.year
    options[:month] = @post.month
  end
  options
end
```

post.rb

```
def to_param # optional
  slug
end

def year
  published_on.year
end

def month
  published_on.strftime('%m')
end
```

view

```
<%= link_to 'post', @post %>
```

Note, for Rails 3.x you might want to use this route definition:

```
resources :posts
match '/:year/:month/:slug', :to => "posts#show", :as => :post, :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :slug => /[a-z0-9\-]+/
```

Is there any badge for answering your own question? ;)

Btw: the [routing_test](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/test/dispatch/routing_test.rb) file is a good place to see what you can do with Rails routing.

**Update:** Using `default_url_options` is a **dead end**. The posted solution works only when there is `@post` variable defined in the controller. If there is, for example, `@posts` variable with Array of posts, we are out of luck (becase `default_url_options` doesn't have access to view variables, like `p` in `@posts.each do |p|`.

So this is still an open problem. Somebody help?

Comment: Badge? There is self learner (if you answered your own question and it has 3 upvotes) and you can accept your answer.

Comment: That was just a joke ;) There's a bigger issue. My solution breaks when I'm dealing with posts in other controllers. Specifically, when there is no @post present (while there may be @posts variable there).

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Bates talked about it in his screen cast "how to add custom routes, make some parameters optional, and add requirements for other parameters."
http://railscasts.com/episodes/70-custom-routes

Comment: Generic routes (map.connect, which Ryan Bates talks about), named_routes and RESTful routes are three different things. I can easily have any URL I want using both generic and named routes. I want to have pretty urls using RESTful routes.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful. You can define a [`default_url_options`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000661) method in your `ApplicationController` that receives a Hash of options that were passed to the url helper and returns a Hash of additional options that you want to use for those urls.

If a post is given as a parameter to `post_path`, it will be assigned to the first (unnassigned) parameter of the route. Haven't tested it, but it might work:

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
  if options[:controller] == "posts" && options[:year].is_a?Post
    post = options[:year]
    {
      :year  => post.created_at.year,
      :month => post.created_at.month,
      :slug  => post.slug
    }
  else
    {}
  end
end
```

I'm in the similar situation, where a post has a language parameter and slug parameter. Writing `post_path(@post)` sends this hash to the `default_url_options` method:

```
{:language=>#<Post id: 1, ...>, :controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}
```

UPDATE: There's a problem that you can't override url parameters from that method. The parameters passed to the url helper take precedence. So you could do something like:

```
post_path(:slug => @post)
```

and:

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
  if options[:controller] == "posts" && options[:slug].is_a?Post
    {
      :year  => options[:slug].created_at.year,
      :month => options[:slug].created_at.month
    }
  else
    {}
  end
end
```

This would work if `Post.to_param` returned the slug. You would only need to add the year and month to the hash.

Comment: Works! Very clever, although very hackish too. Now is there a cleaner way to solve this?

Comment: That's interesting, because it didn't work for me. I could only see that the post instance is passed. Maybe it's because of the plugin you use. I can only get it to work when I pass the post as `:slug => @post`.

Comment: Now I understand: if you set a value in the `options` hash directly as I did by mistake in my first revision, e.g. `options[:year] = 2009` then it's set correctly (as the hash is being passed by reference). So you can actually overwrite given keys.

Comment: Yes, it requires a plugin so that the routes are correct (this is a prerequirement). Check this: http://gist.github.com/303710

Answer (score 1):

You could just save yourself the stress and use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). Its awesome, does the job and you could look at [a screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) by Ryan Bates to get started.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of this question. It's not about slug generation (which itself is trivial), but about friendly dated urls (year/month parts are the hard thing here).