# How to use record attributes in URLs with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, clean-urls

How can I convince rails to use a record attribute in the url for it, in addition to the id?

For example, consider a class `Publication` with an attribute `pub_date`, it would be nice to have a url like

```
 /publications/#{pub_date.year}/#{id}
```

While I can use `to_param` to change the "id" part, I seem to remember that it's a Bad Idea to generate a param with "/" in it. so using something like

```
def to_param
  "#{pub_data.year}/#{super}"
end
```

seems unfeasible. Also it would seem to be impossible with other URLs templates, e.g. if I wanted to use the attribute in another part of the url, e.g.:

```
 /#{pub_date.year}/publications/#{id}
```

I can define routes that match, e.g.

```
  match "/xxx/:foo/:bar" => "ctrlr#act"
```

but I am not sure how I could use the `_url`and `_path` helpers that would be autogenerated.

Comment: This post has the answer you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263488/url-for-of-a-custom-restful-resource-composite-key-not-just-id

Answer (score 0):

you can use :as option

```
get "/xxx/:foo/:bar" => "ctrlr#act", :as => :xxx
```

and then

```
xxx_path(:foo => 'asd', :bar => 'qwe') # "/xxx/asd/qwe"
```

Comment: yes, but these requires me to specify the parameters explicitly all the time, when they are implicit in the object value already, I think