# Mapping domain.com/user/1 to domain.com/loginName

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain-fu

Has anyone tried before using subdomain-fu to change `domain.com/user/1` to `domain.com/UserName` ?

Are there any other plugins to make this happen on rails 3?

Comment: it is not subdomain, btw

Comment: yah man.. but i seen in https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu  there is an option to not use sub domain instead what I want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by "overwriting" the `to_param` method in your User model.

Assuming you are using a User model, as you stated put some code like this in it:

```
  #cleans up the url so it's purdy.
  def to_param
    loginName # you probably want login_name or just name, but whatever it's your code
  end
```

So notice that you now have to change your User#show controller call though, since you really are doing a

```
User.find_by_name(params[:id]
```

Lastly, we should be able to change the routes so that the **last** route in your routes.rb file says:

`match ':id' => 'users#show'`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called pretty URLs.  Take a look here: [Pretty (dated) RESTful URLs in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258321/pretty-dated-restful-urls-in-rails)